# from csv to json selecting the categories from two categorical variables (columns) as keys of the json file

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary, parsing

I have a csv file of the kind:

```
'var0001','var0055','var0054','var0057','var0059'
404,11,1500,31,2010
502,24,38000,31,2010
311,105,46000,31,2011
765,32,28000,25,2010
102,45,67000,25,2011
482,2,34000,25,2011
```

And I want to reorganize them in a json file using the categories of var0057 and var0059 as keys of the json output, just as:

```
[
 {'2010':{
          '31':{
                {'var0001':404,
                 'var0055':11,
                 'var0054':1500},
                {'var0001':502,
                 'var0055':24,
                 'var0054':38000}                
               },
          '25':{
                {'var0001':765,
                 'var0055':32,
                 'var0054':28000}
               }
         },
  '2011':{
          '31':{
                {'var0001':311,
                 'var0055':105,
                 'var0054':46000}               
               },
          '25':{
                {'var0001':102,
                 'var0055':45,
                 'var0054':67000},
                {'var0001':482,
                 'var0055':2,
                 'var0054':34000} 
               }
         }     
 }
]
```

I have tried using to_json but I have not figured any place or function where I can set categories of a third or a fourth variable as keys of the dict formed.

Comment: Can you post the code you attempted to solve this task as a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two nested `defaultdicts` to build the initial dictionary. Then to get a list run them thought a comprehension to get a list of dicts, which can then be dumped to json:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
with open('test.txt') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, quotechar="'")
    header = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        d[row[4]][row[3]].append(dict(zip(header, row[0:3])))
```

`d` is now a dictionary keyed to year. For example:

```
d['2010']['31']
>> [{'var0001': '404', 'var0055': '11', 'var0054': '1500'},
    {'var0001': '502', 'var0055': '24', 'var0054': '38000'}]
```

You can dump it to a list with:

```
import json
json.dumps([{k: v for k, v in d.items()}])
```

Comment: but `d['2010']['31']` should return: `[{'var0001': '404', 'var0055': '11', 'var0054': '1500'},{'var0001': '502', 'var0055': '24', 'var0054': '38000'}]` instead of just one of them

Comment: See update @Tullio -- got confused because your desired output doesn't show lists: `'31':{...` should be `'31':[...`